# My loss is "nan" and accuracy is " 0.0000e+00 " in Transfer learning: InceptionV3

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I am working on transfer learning. My use case is to classify two categories of images. I used InceptionV3 to classify images. When training my model, I am getting **nan** as loss and **0.0000e+00** as accuracy in every epoch. I am using 20 epochs because my data amount is small: I got 1000 images for training and 100 for testing and per batch 5 records.

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
# and a logistic layer -- we have 2 classes
predictions = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)


for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# we chose to train the top 2 inception blocks, i.e. we will freeze
# the first 249 layers and unfreeze the rest:
for layer in model.layers[:249]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[249:]:
   layer.trainable = True

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/Desktop/Transfer/train/',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/Desktop/Transfer/test/',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=1000,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=100)
```

Comment: For the combination of softmax output and binary crossentropy you should use 2 output neurons in the last dense layer, not one. And 'categorical' class_mode for data generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your gradient is exploding. There could be a few reasons for that:

- Check that your input is generated correctly. For example use the `save_to_dir` parameter of `flow_from_directory`
- Since you have a batch size of 5, fix the `steps_per_epoch` from `1000` to `1000/5=200`
- Use `sigmoid` activation instead of `softmax`
- Set a lower learning rate in Adam; to do that you need to create the optimizer separately like `adam = Adam(0.0001)` and pass it in `model.compile(..., optimizer=adam)`
- Try `VGG16` instead of `InceptionV3`

Let us know when you tried all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) for the activation does not make sense in case of single class. Your output value will always be normed by itself, thus equals to 1. The purpose of softmax is to make the values sum up to 1. In case of single value you will get it == 1. I believe at some moment in time you got 0 as predicted value, which resulted in zero division and NaN loss value.

You should either change the number of classes to 2 by:

- `predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)`
- `class_mode='categorical'` in `flow_from_directory`
- `loss="categorical_crossentropy"`

or use the sigmoid activation function for the last layer.

Comment: Used Sigmoid activation function...still issue persists.

Comment: You better try 2 classes.

Comment: Also, marco gave you very good advises. Try to play with hyperparams and find the root of your problem.